# Searching JTable using TableRowSorter in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have several forms in java having JTables in it. All I need is to create a common class ('*TableFilter*') and use this class to filter the table in forms. Here I am passing the JTable, JTextField and the column number to be searched(*if I want to search the whole table I will pass 911 as column number*).

My problem is when I am searching a value that is not in the table, sometimes it doesn't inform that the value is not there sometimes it shows the message for n times and clear the textbox and sometimes it is not searching at all. Is this the right approach for searching a value in a JTable? Can someone help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

**NB:** My JTable contains HTML data and(or) normal object values.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TableFilter {

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

    public TableFilter() {
        System.out.println("Filter Property Enabled");
    }

    public void filterJTable(JTable tab, JTextField filterText, int oncolumn) {// o,1,2 -> for corresponding columns and 911 for whole
        System.out.println("filtering for " + tab.getName());
        if (oncolumn == 911) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tab.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<>((DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel()));
                    sorter = (TableRowSorter<TableModel>) tab.getRowSorter();
                    filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim()));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim()));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim()));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        } else {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tab.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<>((DefaultTableModel) tab.getModel()));
                    sorter = (TableRowSorter<TableModel>) tab.getRowSorter();
                    filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim(), oncolumn));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim(), oncolumn));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText.getText().trim(), oncolumn));
                            if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0) {
                                reload(filterText);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private void reload(JTextField filterText) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No values found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                filterText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The table probably isn't done filtering.  Try placing your `if (sorter.getViewRowCount() == 0)` inside an `invokeLater` call.  By the way, you may want you make use of [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) so you don't get an exception when searching for, say, `(`.

Comment: You don't need the invokeLater(). Code executed in a listener is already executing on the Event Dispatch Thread.